# jQuery Not Working in IE11 On Live Server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-11

I'm using jQuery for the first time and so I've added the jQuery 2.1 library to my ASP.NET project and referenced it from the Master Page like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
```

With all of the files on the web server, the pages work fine in Chrome - all of the jQuery stuff functions as expected.  However, if I load the same pages in IE11 (I haven't had a chance to test other browsers yet), none of the jQuery functionality works.

Interestingly, if I launch IE11 from Visual Studio 2013's development environment, so that it runs the website in IIS express on my dev machine for testing purposes, everything works fine.  So it's clearly not a browser compatibility issue, and it seems that I'm doing things right since it works in Chrome on the web server.

Any ideas what I could try?  Are there any quirks for getting jQuery working in IE?  I've tried referencing the jQuery script file from the individual Web Forms as well as the Master Page, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: Hit F12. What document mode does the Emulation tab say? If it's "IE7 Compatibility Mode", that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the dev tools in IE (hit F12). Can you see JS errors on the console? Can you check dev tools and see if file is actually being requested on the live site and that you aren't getting a 404 for example. Dev tools -> network -> hit play button -> navigate to page and it shows you interactions

Can see a dev tools guide here [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, what a great tool! I've used that, and it's throwing an error in the jQuery script function `jquery.ready.promise` at the line `document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", completed, false );`. Sadly I'm not proficient enough to know if that's the cause of my problem or how to fix it1

Comment: You aren't running the site in compatbility mode or anything like that? JQuery > v2.0 doesn't support older IE versions so being in compatibility mode may cause it to fail. This post mentions possibly related issues http://forums.asp.net/t/1964604.aspx?Error+Microsoft+Visual+Studio+Express+2013+Web. Could try a Jquery version less than 2.0 for backwards compatability

Comment: Nope, not running in Compatibility Mode (and it didn't work when I tried Compatibility Mode, just in case). I've changed out jQuery v2 for v1.11.0 and it works fine in IE11 now, so although I haven't got to the bottom of the problem I'm happy enough and I wasn't using anything that's not supported in v1 anyway.  So, an answer for me but perhaps not for other people with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah we run v1 still. Would love to just be able to close off old IE but still a few clients holding out on 8.

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same problem.
Im using jquery-2.1.0.js in VS2013 and IE11.
I found this solution posted by **jakecigar** http://forum.jquery.com/topic/issue-with-2-1-0-and-ie but did not work with IE11.